# Windows store application incremental loading

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, desktop

So I am trying to get a list to incrementally load for windows desktop. I have this on the GridView:

```
IncrementalLoadingTrigger="Edge"
IncrementalLoadingThreshold="1.5"
```

I listen for the events and it loads the next page. The problem is that when you move the page just a little more, it loads up that and the next like 5-8 pages of results without stopping. This causes a huge hit in performance. Anyone know how to fix this? Any good tutorials you know of for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the previous developer was inserting the new items in himself and not using collectionchanged events to handle what happens. This caused massive slow downs when loading more listings instead of adding one at a time and handling the events more smoothly. I used this as an example to fix this: [Here](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2012/06/10/Metro-Incrementally-load-GridView-and-ListView-with-ISupportIncrementalLoading.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you can just ignore the new request while the previous one is still processing in the virtualized items source and wait for that to finish before you start accepting new requests for more data.